# Privileges given to an Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle

For a business need, I've tried to get the list of (users, roles, ..) whom have a privileges (execute, debug, ...) on an Oracle procedure on an Oracle database. 
Firstly, I've tried to check its script creation but they didn't exist.
Now I want to get the query which can retreive me this information.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, this query can be executed to get the needed result:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS 
WHERE OWNER = 'OFFER' 
  and table_name ='PROC_NAME';
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to get the users to whom the privileges are granted for this procedure.

Comment: VC74's answers gives you that. The query will return a column called `GRANTEE` which can be a role or a user.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure itself doesn't have any "privileges"; they are granted to user or to role.

The only privilege granted on a procedure is `EXECUTE`.

Comment: As of 12c, Code Based Access Control (CBAC) now means stored procs can also have privileges.I'm wondering if the OP's question is about this.